# Include Kendo widget in DropDownList item template

Tags: kendo-ui

I am defining a Kendo DropDownList in Razor syntax:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
    .Name("viewList")   
    .BindTo(Model.Definitions)
    .DataTextField("Name")
    .DataValueField("Name")
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 400px" })
    .Value("Default")
    .TemplateId("item-template"))
```

With an external item template:

```
<script id="item-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <div>
        #= Name #
    </div>
</script>
```

I would like to place a button before the text:

```
<script id="item-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <div>
    @(Html.Kendo().Button()
        .Name("deleteButton")
        .HtmlAttributes( new {type = "button"} )
        .SpriteCssClass("k-icon k-delete")
        .Content("Delete")) 
    #= Name #
    </div>
</script>
```

This fails. In the Chrome debug console I get: 'Uncaught Error: Invalid template'. Is there a way of placing another Kendo UI widget in the template? Examples on the Telerik site and elsewhere don't seem to cover this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a .ToClientTemplate() in your control inside the template. I will also point out that you should give your button a unique name based on the ID data of the template.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Button()
        .Name("deleteButton_"+data.MyID)
        .HtmlAttributes( new {type = "button"} )
        .SpriteCssClass("k-icon k-delete")
        .Content("Delete")
        .ToClientTemplate()
)
```